# PHP discard empty lines on file read

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that looks like this: It will always have the empty line at the bottom, and I cannot remove it manually every time.

```
1601:  01 03 04 5t5gfd# CAR_Z12
1602:  01 01 01 4gfasc# CAR_7CA
"empty line"
```

So the empty line does not say empty line it's just a blank line, how can I remove it when I read the file?

I tried: `$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

No effect:

Since im doing an  `$array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));`
I get `[1603] =>`

I can check for empty values if that's the best way to go about it, but I dont want to introduce another loop for an already large file.

Comment: try this `$fp = preg_replace('^\r?\n','',$fp);`

Comment: @technoKnol this could work however you are missing ending delimiter in your pattern.

Comment: i think that's not needed,

Comment: Yje go;r od tr;;u yjsy ;sthr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$fp = fopen($filename); 
$arr = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

unset($arr[count($arr)-1]);

fwrite($fp,implode("\n", $arr));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: seems like unsetting does not change the size of the array:

Answer (score 1):

`FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` **should** do what you want and the rest of your code seems ok.

Perhaps your file contains different line endings that the one from your OS (eg a *nix file with `\n` on a windows system that expects `\r\n` or vice versa).

Enabling the [`auto_detect_line_endings`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) might solve your problem

Comment: going to enable line endings and see if it fixes the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

One more method i recall is.. `trim()`

```
$str=trim("\n",$str);\\This will trim starting and ending new line character...
$str=ltrim("\n",$str);\\This will trim starting new line character...
$str=rtrim("\n",$str);\\This will trim ending new line character...
```

Thx